# Finding the variance of a sample $\Theta_1 = \frac{X_1+X_3+X_5}{3}$

Tags: probability, statistics, variance

$X_1,X_3$ and $X_5$ are from a population with average = $\mu$ and stdev = $\sigma^2$.

My professor did:

$$V(\Theta_1) = V(\frac{X_1+X_3+X_5}{3}) = \frac{1}{9}(V(X_1)+V(X_3)+V(X_5)) = 1/9 * 3\sigma^2 = \sigma^2/3$$

In another exercise he calculated the expected value of this population this way:

$$E(\Theta_1) = \frac{1}{3}*(E(X_1)+E(X_3)+E(X_5))=\frac{1}{3}(3*\mu) = \mu$$

Why is the 1/3 squared on the variance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ be a real-valued constant.  Let $X$ be a random variable with mean $\operatorname{E}[X] = \mu$ and variance $\operatorname{Var}[X] = \sigma^2$.  Then consider the variance $\operatorname{Var}[aX]$.  Recalling the definition of variance $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[(X - \operatorname{E}[X])^2],$$ we have 
$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}[aX] &= \operatorname{E}[(aX - \operatorname{E}[aX])^2] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[(aX - a\operatorname{E}[X])^2] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[a^2 (X - \operatorname{E}[X])^2] \\
&= a^2 \operatorname{E}[(X - \operatorname{E}[X])^2] \\
&= a^2 \operatorname{Var}[X],
\end{align*}$$ as claimed.

Comment: Isn't the variance also defined as $E[X^2]-E[X]^2$? How does that relate to this?

Comment: @Segmentationfault The formula $\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[X^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2$ is actually derived from the formula I used.  It is not a definition.  You may, however, still use it to prove the desired property, which I leave as an exercise.